# Can .net core 2.2 and 3.1 application slots coexist in the same app service?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-2.1

We currently have two slots in azure app service: staging and production. We just migrated .net core 2.2 to 3.1 and tested it in a separate dev app service. We are about to publish the 3.1 app to staging.

Does anyone know if there are any issues with having one slot running 2.2 and another one 3.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Azure web app` is a `PaaS` service, and we cannot modify the content in it. Because of this, it integrates many environments by default, or supports all our common SDK versions by default.

## If you are not at ease, or when an exception occurs, you can add an Extension to solve possible future problems.

[image]

---

***Test steps:***

1. Create an app service (**jasonp2core22**) which version is .net core 2.1.

   [image]

   Run `dotnet --info`.

   [image]
2. Create an app service (**jasonp2core31**) which version is .net core 3.1.

   [image]

   Run `dotnet --info`

   [image]
3. `Slot` is essentially an app service, so your worries are non-existent, and it can all run normally.

   [image]

   Also run `dotnet --info`.

   [image]