# Create azure web app with multiple stacks

Tags: python, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I am working on a .net core API application, which we would like to include some functionality from an older in-house python3 project, locally we run the python3 code by using ProcessStartInfo classes and methods and opening the returned files.
Now we want to move this application to azure web apps, however on creation you can only select a single runtime, anybody any suggestions on how to get it to work with 2 runtime environments?

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ?

Comment: @jasonPan, Thanks just checked seemed like that is the case. :)
I have accepted your answer as correct :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By default, when you create a webapp (Code hosting), you already have all runtime environments.**

## Suggestion:

1. It is recommended to choose windows platform (support virtual application) when creating webapp. When you find that you cannot use the runtime you need, you can try to install runtime extensions for other programs.
2. It is also possible under Linux and requires command line to operate.

*Related Post:*

[Can .net core 2.2 and 3.1 application slots coexist in the same app service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66428776/can-net-core-2-2-and-3-1-application-slots-coexist-in-the-same-app-service/66432286#66432286)

## Related Pics

1. runtime on portal

   [image]
2. python runtime on kudu.

   [image]
3. nodejs and php.

   [image]
4. check in console.

   [image]